# python get xml element by path

Tags: python, xml

I try to walk through a large xml file, and collect some data. As the location of the data can be find by the path, I used xpath, but no result.

Could someonne suggest what I am doing wrong?

Example of the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rootnode>
    <subnode1>

    </subnode1>
    <subnode2>

    </subnode2>
    <subnode3>
        <listnode>
            <item id="1"><name>test name1</name></item>
            <item id="2"><name>test name2</name></item>
            <item id="3"><name>test name3</name></item>
        </listnode>
    </subnode3>
</rootnode>
```

The code:

```
import lxml.etree as ET

tree = ET.parse('temp/temp.xml')

subtree = tree.xpath('./rootnode/subnode3/listnode')

for next_item in subtree:
    Id = next_item.attrib.get('id')
    name = next_item.find('name').text
    print('{:>20} - {:>20}'.format(name,Id))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pretty close.

**Ex:**

```
import lxml.etree as ET

tree = ET.parse('temp/temp.xml')

subtree = tree.xpath('/rootnode/subnode3/listnode')
for next_item in subtree:
    for item in next_item.findall('item'):
        Id = item.attrib.get('id')
        name = item.find('name').text
        print('{:>20} - {:>20}'.format(name,Id))
```

---

**OR**

```
subtree = tree.xpath('/rootnode/subnode3/listnode/item')
for item in subtree:
    Id = item.attrib.get('id')
    name = item.find('name').text
    print('{:>20} - {:>20}'.format(name,Id))
```

**Output:**

```
  test name1 -                    1
  test name2 -                    2
  test name3 -                    3
```

Comment: Don't just post code. Please explain the problem with the code in the question.